# Filter Data From One Excel Tab, Paste In Another, Clear Filter

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to have an Excel tab that filters and returns the data from another tab based on the input of a text box, then simply clear the data. I used this code:

```
Sub PasteFilteredData()

Declare variables
Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim DestRng As Range

Set the range to be filtered
Set FiltRng = Range("DataTab!A1:Z100")

Filter the range based on a partial match of a string value
FiltRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & "L5" & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

Copy the filtered data to the clipboard
FiltRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Set the destination range where the copied data will be pasted
Set DestRng = Range("SummaryTab!K7:Z7")

Paste the copied data into the destination range
DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Clear the filter
FiltRng.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

But got Runtime 1004.
L5 is the textbox.

A previous solution I used was:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TestTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=[J4] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Where J4 was the textbox, and that works fine, but I need the textbox to be on a different tab, show all of the filtered data from the other tab a few cells beneath it, then clear it when done.

Tried `FiltRng` and `PasteSpecial` and didn't work.

Thanks @jsleshem for the edit.

Comment: `Criteria1:=Worksheets("SummaryTab").Range("L5").Value`

Comment: Also, is `L5` an actual textbox? it looks like a cell address.

Comment: Where is the code ? is it on the same sheet as the TextBox L5 ?

Comment: Yes @tigeravatar. Am I supposed to use the textbox ID (TextBox1) instead?

Comment: Yes the code is on the same sheet as my intended summary tab @CDP1802